# prettier trailing commas error when importing a group

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier, prettier-eslint

I am having an issue where prettier seems to break itself when trying to follow it's trailing comma rules. Here is a sample of what I'm seeing:

**My prettierrc.js file:**

```
module.exports = {
  semi: true,
  trailingComma: "all",
  avoidEscape: true,
  printWidth: 120,
  tabWidth: 3
};
```

**My issue code:**

```
import {
   Button,
   ButtonGroup,
   CardContent,
   CircularProgress,
   Divider,
   TextField,
   useMediaQuery
} from "@material-ui/core";
```

What is happening is that prettier advises to add a trailing comma after **useMediaQuery**.
I add it and then when a save the file, prettier removes the trailing comma causing an error.

**Screenshots:**

[image: Error]

---

###### BEFORE I SAVE             &             AFTER I SAVE

[[image: Before I Save3]
[image: After I Save]

If a import them individually, it works. It's only when I import 6+ on one line.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to add, this happens on any import group, not just my Material-UI imports.

Comment: It doesn't look like your prettier file is having any affect on prettier. Try switching to a .prettierrc file type and using the JSON format that you see here  https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Comment: @JayDev, I tested this by renaming it to .prettierrc, making it json format, and it had the same exact issue as the js file.

Comment: facing same issue. Did you found any solution?

Comment: @YogenDarji, Hello. I'm on a Mac now which doesn't seem to have the issue. From Windows I have confirmed that it still has the issue.

Comment: Does any of you guys know how to solve the issue?

Comment: @allamgr, I don't have any good news for you. I have updated to the latest with same exact results. I can confirm that both the current version I'm on and the newest work on Mac OS but not Windows. My workaround was to split out my imports instead of grouping them. I know, not optimal. If I ever figure it out or an update comes out, I will make sure to come back to this issue and notify everyone.

Comment: Hi @gvanriper, after some hard searching I've fixed this adding "trailingComma": "es5" in my .prettierrc file. Hope this works for you.

Comment: @allamgr, great! Did you want to put that as the answer?

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue and I found the guilty, it's the `source.organizeImports` setting.

If you put the setting to "false", the issue disappears.

If, like me, you want to keep this setting enabled, you can use it like that (array instead of object):

```json
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": [
  "source.organizeImports",
  "source.fixAll.eslint"
],
```

When you use an array, order is respected, so `organizeImports` remove the comma, but `fixAll.eslint` re-add it

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem, but after a hard search I fixed just adding **`trailingComma`** property in your **`.prettierrc`** file

```
    {
        ...,
        "trailingComma": "all",
    }
```

If you still facing any issue just restart the VS Code.